# Google Sign-in Alert: Hide Android Model Name

Tags: gmail, google-account, google

I want to sign-in my Google account on my Android phone (not only Chrome). The rest is said in title.

When signing in with Android, Google emails me the sign-in alert: `a new sign-in on [device name]`. In contrary, on Windows, it's only `a new sign-in on Windows`. How to hide my exact phone model such that it shows `a new sign-in on Android` instead?

I'm rooted, so it may be easier to do so.

Comment: Those emails are generated on Google servers, they are part of your Google account which means they are totally unrelated of Android.

Comment: I know. Except, the device model name is from Android itself. If I can change that, then I've hidden my real model name.

Comment: I'm unsure if hardcoding it as "Android" is possible. While I don't know how Google names it, they may be using their own [device list mapping](https://storage.googleapis.com/play_public/supported_devices.html) for the Play Store.

Comment: So can i spoof as specific device? Like, for example, S22 Ultra?

Comment: By changing the product model on the `build.prop` file (need root access) perhaps (not confirmed, no devices to test). Maybe changing to an unlisted product model may achieve something else, though Android apps might not behave as expected if they depend on the value of the product model.